# parse method and return the result

Tags: javascript

I have this scenario where i have an function that evaluates strings. The problem i have is that this doesnt work with methods.

`JSON.stringify()` cannot stringify methods so i use this replacer function here.

Unfortunetally the function is an string when i try to execute it.

```js
let obj = {
   name: "Max",
   test() {
      return "cool";
   }
}


function parseString(str, obj) {
  let variables = Object.keys(obj).join(",");
  let strData = JSON.stringify(obj, function(key, value) {
    if (typeof value === "function") {
      return value.toString();
    } else {
      return value;
    }
  });
  return new Function(`let {${variables}} = ${strData}; return ${str}; `).call(
    obj
  );
}

console.log(parseString("name", obj)); //expected output: "max"
console.log(parseString("test()", obj)); //expected output: "cool"
```

Is there an way to execute the function and return the result? Some workaround?

Comment: JSON is intended for pure data. It's a language-independent serialization format, it doesn't make sense to put code in it.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let obj = {
   name: "Max",
   test() {
      return "cool";
   }
}


function parseString(str, obj) {
  let variables = Object.keys(obj).join(",");
  let strData = JSON.stringify(obj, function(key, value) {
    if (typeof value === "function") {
      return value();
    } else {
      return value;
    }
  });
  return new Function(`let {${variables}} = ${strData}; return ${str}; `).call(
    obj
  );
}

console.log(parseString("name", obj)); //expected output: "max"
console.log(parseString("test", obj)); //expected output: "cool"
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let obj = {
   name: "Max",
   test() {

      return "cool";
   }
}


function parseString(str, obj) {
  let variables = Object.keys(obj).join(",");
  let strData = JSON.stringify(obj, function(key, value) {
    if (typeof value === "function") {
      return value.toString();
    } else {
      return value;
    }
  });
  return new Function(`let {${variables}} = ${strData}; return ${str}; `).call(
    obj
  );
}

console.log(parseString("name", obj)); //expected output: "max"
console.log(parseString("obj.test()", obj)); //expected output: "cool"
```

Answer (score 0):

You were very close. You just did small two mistake. just use `test` instead of `test()` while calling function in console. and the other is while the type of a value is function, you need to call that value as a function like `value().toString()` instead of `value.toString()`. The rest of the code is perfect.

```js
let obj = {
   name: "Max",
   test() {
      return "cool";
   }
}


function parseString(str, obj) {
  let variables = Object.keys(obj).join(",");
  let strData = JSON.stringify(obj, function(key, value) {
    if (typeof value === "function") {
      return value().toString(); // change value to value()
    } else {
      return value;
    }
  });
  return new Function(`let {${variables}} = ${strData}; return ${str}; `).call(
    obj
  ); 
}

console.log(parseString("name", obj)); //expected output: "max"
console.log(parseString("test", obj)); // Change test() to test
```